# How to get the an embedded video in a PowerPoint?

Tags: c#, video, powerpoint, media

How to get the an embedded video in a PowerPoint. I already know that video are placed in Media folder and that a PPTX file is in fact a zipped file.

Here is my code:

```
 originalSlide = originalSlides[counter];
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape shape in originalSlide.Shapes)
            {
                if(shape.Type == MsoShapeType.msoMedia)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("msoMedia detected...");

                    if (shape.MediaType == PpMediaType.ppMediaTypeMovie)
                    {
                        float x = shape.Left;
                        float y = shape.Top;
                        float w = shape.Width;
                        float h = shape.Height;

                        Console.WriteLine("video detected..."); 
                        ...
```

I'm not able to retrieve the name of the media.

How to make the difference between embedded video and linked video (shape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: >> How to make the difference between embedded video and linked video (shape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName)?

If you query .LinkFormat.SourceFullName, it'll return the path to the linked file OR if the video's embedded, will either return null or throw an error. 

>>How to get the an embedded video 

Please clarify what you're after. Something's missing, I suspect.  "the ??? an embeded video" ... The name of the video, the file or ???

Comment: Embedded videos are renamed to something like _media1.wmv_ by PowerPoint. The file ending remains as in the original file, but the name is gone. Only linked videos retain the original file name and path.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So, it's not possible to get the media name, media1.wmv by example, in the shape object?